# ASP.NET Core in Cloud Foundry

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, reverse-proxy, cloud-foundry

[Kestrel](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer) - as the default "minimal" webserver for ASP.NET Core - works great in development environment. Before activating it in production, installing a reverse-proxy (for example nginx) is strongly [recommended](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/servers.html#choosing-a-server).

> If you intend to deploy your application on a Windows server, you
>   should run IIS as a reverse proxy server that manages and proxies
>   requests to Kestrel. If deploying on Linux, you should run a
>   comparable reverse proxy server such as Apache or Nginx to proxy
>   requests to Kestrel

But what is the recommended way in the cloud, especially in a [Cloud Foundry](https://www.cloudfoundry.org) based cloud host?

Comment: The Cloud Foundry [.NET Core buildpack](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/dotnet-core-buildpack) does not currently support a reverse proxy.  I would suggest opening an issue on that buildpack if you want to use a reverse proxy setup with Kestrel in Cloud Foundry.

Comment: Thank you. But: is is reverse proxy neccessary in the cloud for the normal use?